# Flex text mouse over functionality

Tags: apache-flex, mouseover

I need to develop some mouse over functionality in text field.

I could get the text on click functionality by having htmlText & TextEvent.

Similarly, can i get the mouseover functionality in text field ?

Answer (score 0):

why use htmlText and TextEvent for  on click functionality? click functionality is present in flex.So is mouse over..

> ```
>      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>  <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
>  <mx:Script>
>     <![CDATA[
>         public function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
>         //handle click here..
>         }
>         public function mouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
>                //handle mouse over event here..
>         }
>     ]]>
> </mx:Script>
> <mx:Text x="84" y="72" text="Text" width="212" height="43" click="clickHandler(event)"  mouseOver="mouseOverHandler(event)"/>
> ```

Comment: Sorry, i think the question should be as below. I want the mouse oveer functionality for the multiple text strings in text field. In htmlText i will be having 3 a herf tags, so on mouse over of each hyperlink in htmlText i need to show different data. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private function onMouseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show('Hello Ankur Sharma');
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

Hey this is done using TextField, if u were talkin abt TextField(i used flex3)

Comment: Sorry, i think the question should be as below. I want the mouse oveer functionality for the multiple text strings in text field. In htmlText i will be having 3 a herf tags, so on mouse over of each hyperlink in htmlText i need to show different data. Please help.